# Habilitar acceso por url en Angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

buenas tardes lo que intento es acceder, desde el navegador pegando directamente la ruta por ejemplo: `http://192.168.38.110:8083/user`, me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando accedo por menú o enlaces, si puedo acceder, como lo muestra la siguiente imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien sabe quedo muy agradecido.
muchas gracias.

la configuracion Routes es esta:

> const routes: Routes = [ { path: '', component: MenuTemporalComponent,
>   pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }, { path:
>   'profile', component: ListProfileComponent, canActivate:
>   [AuthGuardService] }, { path: 'user', component: ListUserComponent,
>   canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }, { path: 'error404', component:
>   Error404Component, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }, { path: '**',
>   redirectTo: 'error404' }, ]

Comment: Revisa que para la misma ruta- accion accedas HttpGet, probablemente desde el menu estes accediendo a una ruta httpPost,

Comment: Cómo tienes configurado tus 'pages.routes'?  Y otra cosa, por qué estás trabajando en el puerto 8030 si normalmente en desarrollo angular te abre puerto en el 4200?

Comment: @juandaa1991 Ese codigo lo puedes agregar a tu pregunta. Hay una opcion de editar. Puedes compartir el proyecto? Por lo visto menuTemporalComponent es lo primero que se carga. Posiblemente tengas que poner ese orden despues de el path `user`. Por otro lado, Intentaste con `192.168.38.110:8030/#/user` ? Nota el `#`

Comment: Tambien seria bueno ver como llamas la página desde los enlaces que sí funcionan.

Comment: @Angel gracias por estar respondiendo a mis dudas.
con el comodín o numeral "#", si funciona, pero los usuarios no están acostumbrados a ver ese tipo de enlaces.
pero es raro que cuando trato de ingresar por url no me deje, la unica manera de acceder es por enlaces con la propiedad **routerLink**.
por el momento tuve que implementar **useHash: true**, para asi poder acceder por url.

Comment: Por defecto angular trabaja con el comodín. Para que funcione sin el comodín tienes que configurar unas cuantas cosas. También es bueno que análisis si quieres URL amigables verdaderamente y si las necesitas.  Recuerda que puedes llamar cualquier componente sin necesidad de cambiar URL.

Comment: @Angel por el momento implemente el comodín. pero quiero que los usuarios ingresen por url.